# Want to show show content of particular key in the dropdown form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I created a from where I need to take state and city or District from the user and I have Json file of all the information. I successfully able to fetch the Sates from that JSON file

```
  <label for="state">State</label>
   <select name="state" id="state">
   <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true">Select your State</option>
   </select>
 <label for="District">District</label>
         <select name="District" id="district">
            <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true">Select your district</option>
         </select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = "places.json";
    let data;
     $.getJSON(obj, function (info) {
         data=info;
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#state').append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value.state + 
    '</option>');
      }); 
     });
});
</script>
```

JSON File content

```
{  
         "state":"Delhi (NCT)",
         "districts":[  
            "Central Delhi",
            "East Delhi",
   
         ]
      },
      {  
         "state":"Goa",
         "districts":[  
            "North Goa",
            "South Goa"
         ]
      },
```

What I want when user Select particular state from the dropdown box. then in the district all the districts  of that particular state will display there is this possible to do

I try the same way to fetch the districts from the JSON but in drop down i am getting all districts of every state in object. What I want when user Select particular state from the dropdown box. then in the district dropdown all the districts  of that particular state will display. Is this possible to do. Suppose I select Goa all districts of goa show in dropdown

Comment: What code did you write to do this, currently you only posted the part of the code that works, but I assume you add a listener to the state input select element? Would be a good idea to add that code as well, people are probably not willing to write the code for you, but they are to help you fix your not working code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/adarsh-bhardwaj/pen/PoEGxZQ here is the code i am not able to upload json file